# OpenLayers 2 with different projection is giving blank page

Tags: wms, openlayers-2, proj4js

The code does not give any exception but nothing appears in the browser. This code works with EPSG:4326. Is this the correct way to define projection?

See below for the full code:

```
function init() 
{
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:32645"] = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
            var projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:32645");
    var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                          371399.417972, 2251641.911461,
                          384784.474172,  2236278.339933
                     );

        var options = {
            maxExtent: bounds,
            restrictedExtent:bounds,
            displayProjection: projection,
            allOverlays: false,
            projection: projection,
            units: 'm'
        };

var  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

var ccounties = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                        "Countries02Plugin",
                         "WmsHandler.axd",
                        {
                            srs: projection,
                            version: '1.1.1',
                            layers: 'BHUBANESWAR',
                            format: 'image/png'
                        }                      
        );

map.addLayer(ccounties);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```